# Times font vs Nimbus font

Tags: timesfont, nimbus-font

Please confirm the font families `Times` and `Nimbus` are same else both are different? Please...

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

When I run the file `LaTeX-dvips-PS2PDF` then the font name shows Times but if I run `PDFLaTeX` then the font name shows as `Nimbus`...

Also, note that I was aware that "times.sty" is some what old, need to use `txfonts`, but I need to know how the font name (`Times` to `Nimbus`) changed depends on `TeX` engine? Please advise...

Comment: you don't give  many clues. URW Nimbus is a clone of Times Roman but not the same font but which fonts are associated with any latex font families that you have defined with the non standard names Times and Nimbus depends on code you have not shown

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I will add the `MWE` now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`times` is a very old package (older than LaTeX2e) and not recommended now.

Originally it was set up to use the fonts built in to PostScript laser printers that were just becoming available at the time, so the actual font used depended on the make of printer used but for an Apple (or Sun) laser writer would be Monotype Times Roman.

These days there is a general requirement to embed fonts and the map files in standard distributions should be mapping times to the urw Times Roman clone that is freely available, originally as part of the Ghostscript distribution.

I get this whether pdflatex or dvips/ps2pdf is used with texlive 2021.

**latex-dvips-ps2pdf:**

```
$ pdffonts aa826.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
EREQUQ+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes yes      7  0
```

**pdflatex:**

```
$ pdffonts aa826.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
ABJWAB+NimbusRomNo9L-Regu            Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes      4  0
```

If you want a times roman clone it is better to use a newer package eg

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

The tx fonts are based on the URW fonts but adjusted to fit better with latex usage, especially in math.

Comment: sorry if my question hurts you, is there anyway to get `Times` font name in both either `LaTeX` or `PDFLaTeX`? Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi URW Nimbus Roman is a free clone of Monotype Times Roman. If you want the original Times Roman you need to buy the font.